# How to prevent encoding href attribute by React

Tags: html, reactjs, url-encoding

I'm using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` to render HTML that will be later processed by some third party libraries by replacing some placeholders, for instance here:

`<a href="<%asm_preferences_raw_url%>">Preferences</a>`

`<%asm_preferences_raw_url%>` will be replaced by the actual URL. The problem is that React automatically encodes everything inside `href` and it becomes `&lt;%asm_group_unsubscribe_raw_url%&gt;`. Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: Can't you set this to a state or const variable and set it in href, rather than directly setting it. Please check if that way, the < and > are replaced

Comment: No difference... Why do you think it should be any?

Comment: If that doesnt work, you can try below one using dangerouslysetInnerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```
const hrefLink = "<a href="<%asm_preferences_raw_url%>">Preferences</a>"

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: hrefLink }}>
```

This will have the html with the anchor tag you want inside the div.

Comment: That's the only solution that comes to my mind too, but it looks hacky